# $_POST open in new edited tab

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

```
            <form method="post" target="_blank" action="battle.php" onsubmit="window.open('battle.php','','width=700,height=500,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,status=0,scrollbars=0,resizable=0,left=30,top=0');" >
                <input type="hidden" name="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="password" value="<?php echo $password; ?>"/>
                <input type="submit" value="OPEN TO BATTLE.php"/>
            </form>
```

^^Working but not the way I want it.

I am trying to make this form open a new window at the size `'width=700,height=500,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,status=0,scrollbars=0,resizable=0,left=30,top=0'`when the Submit button is clicked.

I want it so that the $_POST data is transfered through to the new webpage

Comment: the question is: "why"? that is so 90s

Comment: *"Working but not the way I want it."* - Which is what exactly?

Comment: I mean that the $_POST data isn't transferee through to the new tab.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="window.open('http://www.google.com', '_blank', 'toolbar=0,location=0,menubar=0');" >
                <input type="hidden" name="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="password" value="<?php echo $password; ?>"/>
                <input onclick="" type="submit" value="OPEN TO BATTLE.php"/>
            </form>
```

Comment: That makes the webpage open at full screen I want it to be open at a certain width and height.

Comment: now try my updated code

Comment: This works, but the $_POST data at the other end doesn't respond
$username = $_POST['username'];
echo $username;
doesn't respond

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<form method="post" action="battle.php" onsubmit='window.open("battle.php/?width=700&height=500&toolbar=0&menubar=0&location=0&status=0&scrollbars=0&resizable=0&left=30&top=0","_blank");' >
```

Comment: That doesn't work properly

http://localhost/battle.php/?width=700&height=500&toolbar=0&menubar=0&location=0&status=0&scrollbars=0&resizable=0&left=30&top=0

just opens a new tab with this in the url